# Python h5py - efficient access of arrays of ragged arrays

Tags: python, numpy, memory, h5py, ragged

I have a large h5py file with several ragged arrays in a large dataset.  The arrays have one of the following types:

```
# Create types of lists of variable length vectors
vardoub = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=np.dtype('double'))
varint = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=np.dtype('int8'))
```

Within an HDF5 group (grp), I create datasets of N jagged items, e.g.:

```
d = grp.create_dataset("predictions", (N,), dtype=vardoub)
```

and populate d[0], d[1], ..., d[N-1] with long numpy arrays (usually in the hundreds of millions).

Creating these arrays works well, my issue is related to access.  If I want to access a slice from one of the arrays, e.g. d[0][5000:6000] or d[0][50, 89, 100], the memory usage goes through the roof and I believe that it is reading in large sections of the array; I can watch physical memory usage rise from 5-6 GB to 32 GB (size of RAM on the machine) very quickly.  p = d[0] reads the whole array into memory, so I think this is happening and then it is indexing into it.

Is there a better way to do this?  d[n]'s type is a numpy array and I cannot take a ref of it.  I suspect that I could restructure the data so that I have groups for each of the indices e.g. '0/predictions', '1/predictions', ..., but I would prefer not to have to convert this if there is a reasonable alternative.

Thank you,
Marie

Comment: Yes I think you are right. `d[0]` loads the whole array, and the following slice is done on a `ndarray`.  I haven't used `vlen` dtypes much, but I doubt it `h5py` (or HDF5) implements indexing or slicing within such objects.  If `N` isn't too large it's probably more efficient to put each in its own dataset.  You could look at `type(d[0])` to verify this.

Comment: If I load a sample `arr = d[:]`, I get an object dtype array, with each element being a `ndarray`.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj, that's exactly what I saw.  I'll play around with this, but I think that I may need to move away from the ragged arrays and go to the 0/predictions model that I indicated above.  Appreciate your feedback - Marie